# Single Unix Specification version 4 (Issue 7) moved bunch of Real-Time APIs to Base, What Next?

Tags: history, real-time, standard

While reading the standard, I noticed that bunch of APIs were,

1. Introduced in Issue 5 for alignment with POSIX realtime APIs,
2. Marked for option group membership in Issue 6, and
3. Moved to Base in Issue 7 (SUSv4).

**Q**: Does this mean that all systems conforming to "[Unix(R) V7](https://publications.opengroup.org/certifications/unix/x1201)" product standard are realtime systems? What are the actual capability of such system with regard to real-time requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the asker's attempt at guessing.

Just like POSIX Threads, the realtime APIs are found useful in regular applications, coupled with the fact that specifications for these APIs being implementable without major obstacle, operating systems supporting these interfaces become more common, so the standard move them to base; all because POSIX is a prescriptive standard that aims to gather consensus.

Being a realtime API doesn't mean the applications using it is a real-time application. The ability of the operating system (and to an extent, hardware) to guarantee quality of service of these APIs is dependent on various factors, most importantly system load.

It's unreasonable to expect a finite system to be able to serve infinite amount of realtime requests that're beyond its capability. I haven't experience with realtime programming, but it's a sense-based guess of mine that realtime applications have well-defined scope and goals that programmers are obligated to achieve, and beyond which, users of realtime systems are expected to avoid exceeding.